# How to INSERT or UPDATE if duplicate mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have xml values category and subcategory and i want to insert it in database.
this code will be working every day on server checking xml file if there are some changes and if there are it will update mysql database.

I already have code to add records from xml to mysql but there are some problems

> when the file is executed it inserts all data again in mysql instead of checking duplicates and updating if record not exists

```
<?php

// URL is not real this is for example

$url = 'http://xml.com/category'; 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=main_data;charset=utf8", 'root', '');
foreach ($xml -> m as $row){
    $cat = $row->category;
    $subCat = $row->sub_category;
    $sql = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO cat (category, sub_category) VALUES (:cat, :subCat)");
    $sql->bindValue('cat', $cat);
    $sql->bindValue('subCat', $subCat);
    $sql->execute();
}
```

xml example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<category>
    <m>
        <category>Cat 1</category>
        <sub_category>SubCat 1</sub_category>
    </m>

    <m>
        <category>Cat 1</category>
        <sub_category>SubCat 2</sub_category>
    </m>
    <m>
        <category>Cat 2</category>
        <sub_category>SubCat 3</sub_category>
    </m>
</category>
```

Comment: Look this :https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html it should help you

Answer (score 2):

Checking uniqueness is not php's responsibility. It should be MySQL and if MySQL is allowing duplicate records, you have a design flaw! Correct your table design and then use

```
INSERT INTO table(category, sub_category)
VALUES(:cat, :subCat)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE sub_category= values(sub_category); -- and so on
```

if you don't want to update then use

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO ... -- this will insert all rows that is not producing any error
```

Comment: i tried to do this way but result is the same. problem is i cant have unique columns in table because subcategory may be repeated in several categories

Comment: use insert ignore into.. @IvaKobalava